# Plotting respiration signal in frequency domain on y axis while time is on x axis

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft

I have a respiration (breathing) signal and a sampling frequency of 25 Hz and need to detect where is the lowest breathing frequency on a time scale, which should tell me actually when the person became sleepy. Fourier transforms in its classical form doesn't give me much useful information. So, to clarify: the time of measurement should be on the x-axis and the breathing frequency should be on the y-axis. Then, I suppose, lower amplitudes of the signal will show the slower breathing. What should be done with the signal to plot it the way I need?

Comment: Not a programming question - try http://dsp.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: It is actually a scripting code, something that can be written in Matlab. I got an excelent answer from Star Strider in Matlab community.

Comment: Ok - you didn’t tag your question as Matlab (or any other programming language) so it sounded like a DSP theory question rather than a programming question. Try to use helpful and appropriate tags on your questions in future.

Answer (score 2):

All credits for this code go to Star Strider.

```
 D = load('respiratory.txt');
    Fs = 25;                                                    % Sampling Frequency (Hz)
    Fn = Fs/2;                                                  % Nyquist Frequency
    Ts = 1/Fs;                                                  % Sampling Time (sec)
    L = numel(D);
    t = linspace(0, L, L)*Ts;                                   % Time Vector (sec)

figure(1)
plot(t, D)
grid
% axis([0  60    -850  -750])
axis([xlim    -850  -750])
xlabel('Time')
ylabel('Amplitude')

FTD = fft(D-mean(D))/L;                                     % Fourier Transform
Fv = linspace(0, 1, fix(L/2)+1)*Fn;                         % Frequency Vector
Iv = 1:numel(Fv);                                           % Index Vector

figure(2)
plot(Fv, abs(FTD(Iv))*2)
grid
axis([0  2.5    ylim])
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
ylabel('Amplitude')

Wp = [0.35 0.65]/Fn;                                        % Passband Frequency (Normalised)
Ws = [0.30 0.75]/Fn;                                        % Stopband Frequency (Normalised)
Rp =   1;                                                   % Passband Ripple (dB)
Rs =  50;                                                   % Stopband Ripple (dB)
[n,Ws]  = cheb2ord(Wp,Ws,Rp,Rs);                            % Filter Order
[z,p,k] = cheby2(n,Rs,Ws);                                  % Filter Design, Sepcify Bandpass
[sos,g] = zp2sos(z,p,k);                                    % Convert To Second-Order-Section For Stability

figure(3)
freqz(sos, 2^16, Fs)                                        % Filter Bode Plot

D_filtered = filtfilt(sos, g, D);                           % Filter Signal

[pks,locs] = findpeaks(D_filtered, 'MinPeakDist',40);

figure(4)
plot(t, D_filtered)
hold on
plot(t(locs), pks, '^r')
hold off
grid
% axis([0  60    ylim])
axis([0  60    -15  15])
xlabel('Time')
ylabel('Amplitude')

tdif = diff([0 t(locs)]);                                   % Time Difference Between Peaks (sec)
Dfrq = 60./tdif;                                            % Frequency (Respirations/Minute)

figure(5)
plot(t(locs), Dfrq)
grid
axis([xlim    10  40])
xlabel('Time (sec)')
ylabel('Frequency (minute^{-1})')
```